# Amazon EC2 Instance reachability check failed host='169.254.169.254', port=80 Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2

I do not know what happened to my machine that this morning she began to exhibit this error.

I already gave DETECH and Atach volume, restarted it several times but not back, and it can no longer connect to the machine.

Already created an image and climbed a new machine that gets the same mistake, I do not know what to do. I can not connect the machine to do anything!

I'm using Ubuntu in this machine, if Would anyone can help me I thank

```
* Stopping load modules from /etc/modules[74G OK 

cloud-init-nonethttp://15.68: waiting 120 seconds for network device

cloud-init-nonethttp://135.68: gave up waiting for a network device.

Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'init' at Thu, 16 Jun 2016 22:37:22 +0000. Up 136.13 seconds.

ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++Net device info++++++++++++++++++++

ci-info: +--------+-------+---------+------+-------------------+

ci-info: | Device | Up | Address | Mask | Hw-Address |

ci-info: +--------+-------+---------+------+-------------------+

ci-info: | lo | False | . | . | . |

ci-info: | eth0 | False | . | . | 02:b1:18:c0:a2:37 |

ci-info: +--------+-------+---------+------+-------------------+

ci-info: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Route info failed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

> 2016-06-16 22:37:23,043 - url_helper.pyWARNING: Calling
>   'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed
>   0/120s: request error
>
> 2016-06-16 22:37:24,047 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling
>   'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed
>   [1/120s]: request error [HTTPConnectionPool(host='169.254.169.254',
>   port=80): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection
>   aborted.', error(101, 'Network is unreachable')))]
>
> 2016-06-16 22:37:25,051 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling
>   'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed
>   [2/120s]: request error [HTTPConnectionPool(host='169.254.169.254',
>   port=80): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection
>   aborted.', error(101, 'Network is unreachable')))]

Comment: Enter your amazon console, verify the termination protection is active and reboot your instance, also check the security groups available and used, make sure the ports you're trying to reach are open and listening.

Comment: Already I verified this, and he is with all released exits and even then the error continues, it seems that he can not connect with this ip that from what I researched is a return ip aws.
I think this error started after I did an image of the server and the image also this with the same error ...

Comment: This ip is your private IP - it also has the public and possibly elastic (if defined) IPs - you can also check the instance name and what IPs and AMI rules are defined for this private IP

Comment: This is the second time it happens, I create image of a Linux instance and then I can no longer connect to the machine it is presenting validation issue.

Comment: Create Elastic IP for the instance and make sure your machine runs over Elastic IP - than the instance name and the IPs will survive.

Comment: @dmitryro 169.254.169.254 is **not** this machine's private IP address.  Also, the messages mentioning this address are not related to the problem.  169.254.169.254 is the standard address of the [EC2 metadata service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval).  These log entries are symptoms of the problem, but unrelated to the problem.  The problem is that something about the networking configuration of these instances is being done incorrectly.